# Playing RTSP Audio Stream with MediaElementJS player

Tags: mediaelement.js

I want to play "RTSP Audio Stream" using "MediaElementJS" player (mediaelementjs.com). I tried to update the  TAG with RTSP url but it did not played the audio successfully.

Then I tried to use the same RTSP stream in VLC Player and it worked there. Also want to let you know VLC showed the stream as "MPEG AAC Audio (mp4a)" .

I tried the code on Firefox , IE 9.0 , Chrome 18 . I know that the browsers support only specific type of audio format so I tried all the combination on each of the browsers. See below code which I used (look at "type" attribute).

```
<h2>wma</h2>
<audio id="player2" src="rtsp://xx.xxxx.xxxx/D/445/117988/v0001/reflector:44444" type="audio/wma" controls="controls">      
</audio>    


<h2>m4a</h2>
<audio id="player2" src="rtsp://xx.xxxx.xxxx/D/445/117988/v0001/reflector:44444" type="audio/mp4" controls="controls">      
</audio>    

<h2>MP3</h2>
<audio id="player2" src="rtsp://xx.xxxx.xxxx/D/445/117988/v0001/reflector:44444" type="audio/mp3" controls="controls">      
</audio>    

<h2>wav</h2>
<audio id="player2" src="rtsp://xx.xxxx.xxxx/D/445/117988/v0001/reflector:44444" type="audio/wav" controls="controls">      
</audio>    

<h2>mpeg</h2>
<audio id="player2" src="rtsp://xx.xxxx.xxxx/D/445/117988/v0001/reflector:44444" type="audio/mpeg" controls="controls">     
</audio>
```

1) Has anyone successfully run RTSP stream on MediaElementJS player ? If YES please share the code/configuration which you used ?

2) Do you know of any sample working RTSP url which I can test against my player ? I searched a lot on net but non of the RTSP url is working one.

Thanks in advance for all your help.